# How to pass environment variables running Prisma server in a single docker container

Tags: docker, yaml, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

The docker-compose.yml example contained in the docs works great for local development where people probably have multiple services run with docker:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:__LATEST_PRISMA_VERSION__
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        managementApiSecret: __YOUR_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET__
        port: __YOUR_PRISMA_SERVER_PORT__
        databases:
          default:
            connector: __YOUR_DATABASE_CONNECTOR__
            migrations: __ENABLE_DB_MIGRATIONS__
            host: __YOUR_DATABASE_HOST__
            port: __YOUR_DATABASE_PORT__
            user: __YOUR_DATABASE_USER__
            password: __YOUR_DATABASE_PASSWORD__
  mongo:
    image: mongo:__LATEST_PRISMA_VERSION__
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo:/var/lib/mongo
```

However, in production there is no db running in a container. Indeed we're using a DBaaS to host our db. The db we're using is Mongo.

Thus we need to switch from `docker-compose up` to `docker run...` for the Prisma server.

The problem we're facing is how to set all the environment variables needed for the Prisma container to run.

I see two possible options:

1. Pass down single variables to the container
2. Pass down just the variable `PRISMA_CONFIG_PATH` that points to an yml config file, for example, `prisma_config.yml`

### Option 1

In the docker-compose.yml there the `PRISMA_CONFIG` variable is passed as multi-line string.

Searching on the Internet I found that the corresponding list of the single variables should be:

```
      PORT: $PORT
      SCHEMA_MANAGER_SECRET: $SCHEMA_MANAGER_SECRET
      SCHEMA_MANAGER_ENDPOINT: $SCHEMA_MANAGER_ENDPOINT
      SQL_CLIENT_HOST_CLIENT1: $SQL_CLIENT_HOST
      SQL_CLIENT_HOST_READONLY_CLIENT1: $SQL_CLIENT_HOST
      SQL_CLIENT_HOST: $SQL_CLIENT_HOST
      SQL_CLIENT_PORT: $SQL_CLIENT_PORT
      SQL_CLIENT_USER: $SQL_CLIENT_USER
      SQL_CLIENT_PASSWORD: $SQL_CLIENT_PASSWORD
      SQL_CLIENT_CONNECTION_LIMIT: 10
      SQL_INTERNAL_HOST: $SQL_INTERNAL_HOST
      SQL_INTERNAL_PORT: $SQL_INTERNAL_PORT
      SQL_INTERNAL_USER: $SQL_INTERNAL_USER
      SQL_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: $SQL_INTERNAL_PASSWORD
      SQL_INTERNAL_DATABASE: $SQL_INTERNAL_DATABASE
      CLUSTER_ADDRESS: $CLUSTER_ADDRESS
      SQL_INTERNAL_CONNECTION_LIMIT: 10
      CLUSTER_PUBLIC_KEY: $CLUSTER_PUBLIC_KEY
      BUGSNAG_API_KEY: ""
      ENABLE_METRICS: "0"
      JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx1G"
```

#### docker

All those var are set in an env file

`docker run -p 4466:4466 --env-file prisma.env prismagraphql/prisma:1.25`

They seem to work fine for SQL databases, but not for Mongo.

Either I set the wrong values or the variables names when using Mongo differ.

### Option 2

Passing a single env var like `PRISMA_CONFIG_PATH=prisma.config.yml` when running the container:

`docker run -p 4466:4466 -e PRISMA_CONFIG_PATH=prisma.config.yml  prismagraphql/prisma:1.25`

I'm gettting the following error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load Prisma config: java.io.FileNotFoundException: prisma_config.yml (No such file or directory)`

I do not know what is the working directory for the prisma docker image. I guess that would solve it.

## EDIT

I was able to make it work with Option#2

```
docker run \
-e PRISMA_CONFIG_PATH="/prisma.yml" \
-v "$(pwd)/env/prisma_config.yml":"/prisma.yml" \"  \
-p 4466:4466 \
prismagraphql/prisma:1.25
```

**prisma_config.yml**

```
port: 4466
databases:
  default:
    connector: mongo
    uri: __YOUR_MONGO_URI__
    database: __YOUR_MONGO_DB__
```

Comment: There's no rule against using Docker Compose for only a single service.  Can you comment out the local MongoDB server and otherwise adapt your existing config file?

Comment: I am aware of that. However it should not work with Docker Compose only, that would be a limitation. Though I will resort to it if this question gets no solution.